# GWT -- Reliably get unicode value from keycode in keypress

Tags: gwt

I have a need to get the unicode value for a specific keydown event in GWT. All the references I have seen so far suggest doing something like `char c = (char)keyCode` however this does not seem to work (Does not produce the char/string I was expecting -- especially when the input is japanese)

My code is as follows:

```
DOM.setEventListener(documentElement, new EventListener() {

            public void onBrowserEvent(Event event) {
                int keycode = event.getKeyCode();

                   char c=(char)keyCode;     
                   String insertText = String.valueOf(c);
                   // Next I insert the string into the DOM as a text node.

            }
        });


        DOM.sinkEvents(documentElement, Event.ONKEYDOWN);
```

I need to ensure that the value of `insertText` corresponds to what the user expects to be inserted when they hit the keyboard or use an IME input editor to input japanese chars.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try with [KeyCodeEvent#getNativeKeyCode()](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/event/dom/client/KeyCodeEvent.html#getNativeKeyCode%28%29) to get the native key code. These key codes are enumerated in the [KeyCodes](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/event/dom/client/KeyCodes.html) class.

```
char ch = (char)keyDownEvent.getNativeKeyCode()
```

Please have a look at post [Mnemonics in GWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22013201/mnemonics-in-gwt/22021108#22021108) that is asked in the same context.

Answer (score 1):

KeyDown and KeyUp are about the keys depressed on the keyboard. If you're interested in more high-level events that results from these keys (and possibly combine them, e.g. `Shift` and `A` produces an uppercase `A`) then listen to the KeyPress events.

Comment: This seems to work with regular keyboard events. However, the google IME does not to produce keypress events when used. It seems it only produces keydown and keyup events. Any idea how I can workaround this? I need my users to be able to use an IME like: http://www.google.com/ime/